# Quelles seraient d’autres façons plus jolies, plus claires et plus concises de tourner la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Nous avons parfois tendance à rendre malsain un aliment sain, en cela qu’en rajoutant des sauces ou vinaigrettes industrielles, qui ne renferment rien autre que du sel, du sucre, et de la graisse, à de la salade ou à des légumes, cela vient contrecarrer/gâcher/annuler les bienfaits de ces aliments qui se veulent, à l’état naturel, bénéfiques pour la santé.

Comment: Pour être plus concis, une bonne solution est de couper la phrase en plusieurs. Ca pourrait aussi être le cas de cette question qui à mon avis mériterait d'être scindée en sujets dédiés et focalisés sur des points spécifiques :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

« Contrecarrer »  n'est pas ce qu'il y a de plus idiomatique dans ce contexte. D'après le  TLFi, « S'opposer ... en suscitant des obstacles » sont  les  termes qui  cernent ce concept, et il est bien évident que les  méfaits  des aliments plus ou moins nocifs  ne sont pas manifestés par  des obstacles aux apports bénéfiques des aliments sains mais le plus souvent par une action indépendante. Les graisses  alimentaires, par  exemple,  n'ont  aucun effet sur l'absorption des vitamines et des minéraux, tous deux  étant des éléments  nutritifs majeurs dans les légumes, avec  les fibres  alimentaires.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contrecarrer))   CONTRECARRER, verbe trans.
>
> **S'opposer au déroulement d'une action *en suscitant des obstacles***. >Synon. contrarier, contrer :
>
> - Ce qu'il faut reprocher à Jules Favre, c'est d'être venu, lui, le grand orateur, contrecarrer l'élection de Rochefort, le grand pamphlétaire. Hugo, Correspondance,1869, p. 202.

« Gâcher » et « annuler » ne  conviennent pas mieux. L'idée n'est pas saine, mais  elle peut être « récupérée ».

- Nous avons parfois tendance à faire d'une diète fondamentalement saine une diète moins  qu'idéale, en cela qu’en rajoutant aux produits qui la composent (salades, légumes, fruits)  des sauces ou vinaigrettes industrielles qui ne renferment rien d'autre que du sel, du sucre, et de la graisse, on surcharge l'organisme de nutriments qui absorbés en  excès  sont  nocifs, et que,   d'ailleurs, les nourritures de base (salades, légumes, fruits) nous  fournissent déjà en quantités suffisantes.

<sub>Note : il existe certains cas d'« annulation », et fait surprenant dont je viens de me souvenir, les fibres alimentaires empêchent l'absorption de la vitamine C, mais il s'agit seulement des  fibres alimentaires artificielles  (c'est à dire que toute  préparation dans laquelle serait utilisé  ce nutriment artificiel pourrait vraiment  être appelé  « junk food »).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

***Contrecarrer***, ***annuler*** et ***gâcher*** vont bien, tu peux aussi dire ***annihiler***, plus fort.

Sinon, je remplacerais *de la **graisse*** par *des **matières grasses***.